# WPF TaskScheduler. Is there DispatcherPriority when scheduling to FromCurrentSynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, wpf

For the below code, is there a DispatcherPriority when the "MethodRunOnUIThread" scheduled ? I assume it might be "Normal" but not sure how to confirm it. Or the ContinueWith block actually wait and being executed immediately once the GUI thread is available ?

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => BackgroundMethodCall())
    .ContinueWith(t => MethodRunOnUIThread()
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume it might be "Normal" but not sure how to confirm it

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The delegate is put in the dispatcher queue at a priority of Normal.

`ContinueWith` continues task with a continuation, using given task scheduler. For `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` it posts a delegate to the sync context. It doesn't block and wait "availability" of UI thread.

Comment: God ~~ I search through DispatcherPriority and TaskScheudler but couldn't find anything. Not knowing the answer is at FromCurrentSynchronizationContext. jeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ...